# Odd graphing issue

Tags: r, plot

Consider the following plot:

```
 par(xaxs='i',yaxs='i')
 q = c(1000000,1051548,1073218,1087563,1097765,1109949,1113169,1124302,1134923,1137264,1132633,1235922,1351977,1474207,1602776,1746385,1905937,2077873,2276724,2487994,2718546,2939262,3209654,3543057,3858329,4243562,4301907,4332465,4392545,4412729,4429758)
 x <- seq(0,30, by = 1)
 plot(x, q, type = "l", bty = "L", ylim = c(0, max(q2)), xlim = c(0,30), xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n', xlab = "", ylab = "")
 points(20, q[20])
```

[image]

I am plotting the line `q` and the point with coordinates `(20,q[20])`. The weird thing is that the point doesn't get plotted on the line, while it actually belongs to the line..

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I have been trying to solve this problem for over an hour!!

Thanks!

Comment: Do `points(20, q[21])`. Your `x` vector sequence is from 0 to 30, but R indexes starting from 1. 20 in your `x` is the 21st element.

Comment: I think I have been in front of a screen for too long today. Very obvious mistakes. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: No worries. Happens to all of us.

Answer (score 1):

R starts it's index with 1.
That means you have to run `points(20, q[21])` do get the point on the line.